# onload Javascript clock needs fixing

Tags: javascript, clock

Javascript clock.
expected result: Display the date and time.
problem: does not display

[The display of the clock/time in the top left][1]

This code should insert the time into the div with ID value of 'time'. There is a setTimeout function which I suspect is not being utilized properly. My problem is the time not showing. 
I'm missing something here because the time doesn't show. Please help me fix it.

```
 <script>
        var dayArray= ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
        var monthArray= ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

        function getTime() {
            var today = newDate();     


        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        var d = dayArray[today.getDay()];
        var mo = monthArray[today.getMonth()];
        var y = today.getFullYear();

        var mm = correctDigit(m);
        var ss = correctDigit(s);

        document.getElementById('time')
        .innerHTML = "<br><h1 class='large'>"+h+":"+mm+":"+ss+"</h1>&nbsp;<span class='dark'>"+d+",</span>&nbsp;<span class='dark'>"+mo+"</span>&nbsp;<span class='dark'>"+y+"</span>";


        var t = setTimeout (function() {
            getTime();
        }, 1000);

        function correctDigit(i){
            if(i < 10){
                i = "0" + i;
            }
            return i; 
        };
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getTime()" class="color-4">
    <section>
        <div class='time color-0' id="time"></div>
```

Comment: `onload="t"` makes no sense...it should be the name of a function, not an out-of-scope variable. try `onload="getTime()"` instead

Comment: i knw thanks. twas an edit i made. ADyson :)

Comment: yous seem to have erased all your code...

Comment: Is there code to go along with this question?

Comment: @AnonymousSB there used to be...check the revision history

Comment: @Gray please put your original code back so future visitors understand the question.

Comment: Okay. I've put it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed your immediate problem by

- changing the `body`'s `onload` attribute to call the function you want to run, `getTime()`
- putting a space between `new` and `Date` in `var today = newDate()`.

The calendar is now being added to the DOM and updating every second, but your calendar logic seems still to have some issues. (Hint: it works when the minutes and seconds are less than 10; since this wasn't the main part of your question, I'm leaving it as an exercise for you to fix it yourself -- that's how you learn!)

```html
<script>
            var dayArray= ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
            var monthArray= ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

            function getTime() {
                var today = new Date();     
            

            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            var d = dayArray[today.getDay()];
            var mo = monthArray[today.getMonth()];
            var y = today.getFullYear();

            m = correctDigit(m);
            s = correctDigit(s);
            
            document.getElementById('time')
            .innerHTML = "<br><h1 class='large'>"+h+":"+m+":"+s+"</h1>&nbsp;<span class='dark'>"+d+",</span>&nbsp;<span class='dark'>"+mo+"</span>&nbsp;<span class='dark'>"+y+"</span>";
           
            
            setTimeout (function() {
                getTime();
            }, 1000);

            function correctDigit(i){
                if(i < 10){
                    i = "0" + i;
                    return i; 
                }
            };
        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="getTime()" class="color-4">
        <section>
            <div class='time color-0' id="time"></div>
            <div>
                <div class="news scroll color-1">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="ellipsis"><h4 class="dark"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>&nbsp;Title 1</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</p></li>
                        <li class="ellipsis"><h4 class="dark"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>&nbsp;Title 2</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</p></li>
                        <li class="ellipsis"><h4 class="dark"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>&nbsp;Title 3</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</p></li>
                        <li class="ellipsis"><h4 class="dark"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>&nbsp;Title 4</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</p></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks nvioli. I was blind to the error of: new Date(); hahaha I'm so green. You're very good. Both of you.

Comment: Great! If I've fixed your problem please click the check mark to accept my answer (p.s. if you had the console open, or even in the SO snippet view, that error was reported; that's how I found it)

Comment: i just realized that I think while you were sending the reply. I need more practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working working example with some notable differences.

- I put the `setTimeout` outside the `getTime` function
- I used `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`
- I used JavaScript's `String.padStart()` to fill in the missing 0

As for `setInterval`, you can assign that to a variable, and call `clearInterval(variableName)` if you want to stop the clock. Assigning `setTimeout` to a variable doesn't do anything for you.

If you want to see a much easier implementation using momentJS, check out the demo at the bottom

```js
var dayArray = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    monthArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

function getTime() {
  var today = new Date(),
      h = today.getHours(),
      m = today.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
      s = today.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
      d = dayArray[today.getDay()],
      mo = monthArray[today.getMonth()],
      y = today.getFullYear();
  
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 
  `<br>` +
  `<h1 class='large'>${h}:${m}:${s}</h1>&nbsp;` +
  `<span class='dark'>${d},</span>&nbsp;` +
  `<span class='dark'>${mo}</span>&nbsp;` + 
  `<span class='dark'>${y}</span>`;

};

setInterval (function() {
  getTime();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"><div>
```

## Bonus (using momentJS)

```js
function getTime() {
  var today = moment(),
      time = today.format('HH:mm:ss'),
      date = today.format('dddd, MMMM, YYYY');
  
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =
  `<br>` + 
  `<h1 class='large'>${time}</h1>` +
  `<span class='dark'>${date}</span>`
};

setInterval (function() {
  getTime();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: This is an improvement.Thank you AnonymousSB.